# Compile PJSUA on OS X 10.9

Tags: python, sip, osx-mavericks, pjsip

First time using stackoverflow, please tell me, if I'm doing something wrong!

I want to use [PJSIP 2.1](http://www.pjsip.org)s python module (wrapper). I tried it like so:

1. Read the [documentation](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Build_Install).
2. Check the requirements accordingly. This is my setup:

   - OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)
   - GNU Make 3.81
   - binutils 2.23.2 (probably via Macports.. not actually sure)
   - Apple LLVM 5.0
3. Download v2.1: pjproject-2.1.tar.bz2 and extracted it into my home dir.
4. Cd into pjproject-2.1 and run this in terminal: `./configure && make dep && make`.

When it comes to this line (which is during make, I believe): `gcc -o ../bin/pjmedia-test-i386-apple-darwin13.0.0`, the following error gets thrown right into my face :/

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_aes_icm_advance_ismacryp", referenced from:
_aes_icm_encrypt_ismacryp in libsrtp-i386-apple-darwin13.0.0.a(aes_icm.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjmedia-test-i386-apple-darwin13.0.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pjmedia-test] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The script then aborts.

Do you have any suggestions, what might be the problem, or how to avoid it? Will be glad for any help!

Would it help, to force gcc to compile to 32 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am not sure, if this solves your problem, but for me it worked:

> Disable SRTP (Secure Real-Time Transport Protocol)

Add the following to the file **pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h**

> #define PJMEDIA_HAS_SRTP  0

make again - should work.

The right solution would be to reimplement the missing structure in the c code. Probably better to wait for a patch.

Comment: Prevents the problem. Now `make` fails somewhere else, though :/ Anyway, I'm giving up now. Isn't worth the trouble, to me. Thank you, Simon :)